# Insert information from REST API in a table view

Tags: xcode, rest, swift4

I after asking another question today and fixed my Swift 4.2 code, I realized that I can't debug the app because of some profiles.

[Errors shown when Testing application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNqgJ.png)

The app also crashes on launch so there is not much I can do for now. I believe that the issue is how I am getting the information from the webserver (currently my computer). I am quite new to this, so i might have some mistakes in my code, so bear with me.

```
import UIKit

class InfoTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    //MARK: Properties
    class Produs {
        var nume: String!
        var codBare: String!

        init(nume: String, codBare: String) {
            self.nume = nume
            self.codBare = codBare
        }
    }

    var produse = [Produs]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Load elements from server, theoretically
        loadProducts()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return produse.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.
        let cellIdentifier = "InfoTableViewCell"

        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? InfoTableViewCell  else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of InfoTableViewCell.")
        }

        // Fetches the appropriate meal for the data source layout.
        let produs = produse[indexPath.row]

        cell.nameMain.text = produs.nume
        cell.nameInfo.text = produs.codBare

        return cell
    }
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }

    //MARK: Private Methods
    private func loadProducts() { //This function retrieves information in a JSON format from the server
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "192.168.0.145")!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let json = try decoder.decode([[String]].self, from: data!)
                print(json)
                for produs in json {
                    print(produs)
                    var nume_prod: String = produs[0] // Numele produsului
                    var cod_ext: String = produs[1]   // Codul de bare al produsului
                    var prod_obj = Produs(nume: nume_prod, codBare: cod_ext)
                    self.produse.append(prod_obj)
                }
            } catch {
                print("JSON Serialization error")
            }
        }).resume()
    }
}
```

I am getting the information from the server in a JSON file that is an array of arrays and looks like this:

```
[
  [
    "product1",
    "code1"
  ],
  [
    "product2",
    "code2"
  ],
  [
    "product3",
    "code3"
  ]
]
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't send the JSON as array of arrays, send it as array of dictionaries. It simplifies the decoding considerably.

```
[
  {"name":"product1", "code":"code1"},
  {"name":"product2", "code":"code2"},
  {"name":"product3", "code":"code3"}
]
```

Then declare the model as struct and **never declare properties as implicit unwrapped optional which are initialized with non-optional values**. If you need optionals declare them as regular optional (`?`) otherwise non-optional

```
struct Produs {
    let name: String
    let code: String
}
```

Replace `loadProducts` with

```
private func loadProducts() { //This function retrieves information in a JSON format from the server
    let url = URL(string: "192.168.0.145")!

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {[unowned self] data, response, error in
        if let error = error { print(error); return }
        do {
            self.produse = try JSONDecoder().decode([Produs].self, from: data!)
            print(self.produse)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

And replace `cellForRowAt` with

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "InfoTableViewCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! InfoTableViewCell            

    // Fetches the appropriate meal for the data source layout.
    let produs = produse[indexPath.row]

    cell.nameMain.text = produs.name
    cell.nameInfo.text = produs.code

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I have one question, though, every time i make an async call, to i need to DispatchQueue to reload the data? Also, i thought the declaring variables with "!" makes them as the opposite of optional, required.

Comment: Yes, you have to call `reloadData` on the main thread after receiving the data. No, the opposite of optional is non-optional (no question or exclamation mark)

Comment: One more thing, do I need to modify something if i use the URL as my computer's local IP? Will it automatically go there as it would be a website?

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed. Would you mind editng the code to put in the url a `http://` as well? The rows weren't loading until I changed that.

Comment: Just replace `192.168.0.145` with `http://myserver.com/api` or better `https...` `api` is the REST address. Paste the URL in a browser. It must display the JSON output.